# Setting value of struct reference using sscanf

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes a reference to a struct and uses sscanf to set value. However, it is complaining that

`format %u expects type int* but argument has type int`

```
void SetStruct(struct &mystruct){
   std::string s = "test";
   sscanf(s.c_str(), "%u", mystruct.value);
}
```

I've tried using all the `&` and `*` operators I can think of..

I am also open to not using sscanf if C++ has a better way.

Comment: The address-of operator `&` is the correct one to use in this case, but in the right place. As in `&mystruct.value`. Of course, that requires you to pass the structure by reference, and if you don't know how to do that then please get [a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), or go through your class-notes more thoroughly. And consider C++ functions like [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Also, considering the faulty input in the partial [mcve] you show, never forget to check for errors!

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` expects you to pass it a *pointer* to the variable where it can write to.  But you are not passing a *pointer* to the variable, you are passing the *value* of the variable instead.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.  You need to use the `&` address operator to create such a pointer.

Also, in `sscanf()`, the `%u` specifier expects a *pointer* to an `unsigned int`, not to an `int`.

Try this:

```cpp
struct mystruct {
    unsigned int value;
};

void SetStruct(mystruct &ms){
   std::string s = "12345";
   sscanf(s.c_str(), "%u", &(ms.value));
}
```

If you want `value` to be an `int` then you need to use `%d` instead:

```cpp
struct mystruct {
    int value;
};

void SetStruct(mystruct &ms){
   std::string s = "12345";
   sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d", &(ms.value));
}
```

For these reasons, it is better to instead use C++-style type-safe parsing via the `operator>>` of `std::istream`, or a function like `std::stoi()` or `std::stoul()`, rather than use C-style parsing via `sscanf()`.